# How does session_length is calculated by Fabric Answers?

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

currently, the given `session length` is about 0.25s, which is maybe no more than the initialisation time.

Could you tell me how does it work?

[the doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-metrics.html#sessions) didn't help me much.

I currently initialize Fabrics like that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "MainActivity: onCreate");

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Answers());

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todd from Fabric here.

It looks like you are reporting the length in seconds so it is reporting 25 seconds not .25 seconds. We don't report fractions of seconds anywhere in the dashboard.

Comment: I think I well saw the information I talked about in my topic. [here](https://i.imgur.com/ZZLbj30.png) is a part of a screenshot of the daily summary I just received.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Yes, when the time value is <1 minute, we put the s behind the overall statement. This is grammatically correct, however, I'll note it to the team as a point of confusion.