# Understanding Fabric Daily Summary Email

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

We're having trouble understanding the numbers in the daily summary emails we get from Fabric.
A search on SO only shows one [somewhat-related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514914/how-does-session-length-is-calculated-by-fabric-answers/42517106#42517106).

Here are the emails from 2 consecutive days:
[image]
[image]

Our questions are:

1. Does “Monthly Active” mean over the last 30 days? If so, how can there be a 36% drop in 1 day if the counts went from 101 to 93 (an 8% drop)?
2. Why does “Daily Active” show a 75% drop if the current day is 1 and the previous day was 0?
3. Why does “Total Sessions” show a 94% drop if the current day is 1 and the previous day was 0?
4. Does the “Time in App per User” mean the average for the month or for the prior day? If it's for the month, why would 1 extra session cause the value to change so much? If it's for the day, why does it show “11:33m” even though the Total Sessions was 0?
5. Sometimes the “Time in App per User” ends in an “m” and sometimes it ends in an “s”. For example, “11:33m” and “0:44s”. Does that mean that “11:33m” is “11 hours and 33 minutes” and “0:44s” is “0 minutes and 44 seconds”? Or does the “11:33m” still mean “11 minutes and 33 seconds” and I should ignore the suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. Todd from Fabric here. The % change is actually % difference vs. what we expected based on the previous behavior of your app. This compensates for day of week etc.

The long session when getting zero, suggests that either the session was live/not reported to us at UTC midnight. The session gets created on session start and the duration gets set at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Todd, Do we get same thing when we integrate firebase analytics. I am asking coz fabric now firebase. So do have such thing?